# preventing access to php files using htaccess doesnot allow ajax to use php files

Tags: .htaccess

i am using the following code in `.htaccess` to prevent access to `php` files from the browser

```
<Files ~ "\.php">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

the problem whit that is that when i deny access to php files ajax cannot use those `php` files either... how can i solve this... any help would be appreciated... thanks in advance... :)

Comment: Well if you prevent access to a file, it is prevented. Seems to work OK. I think you have a design bug, or I don't know what you are trying to ask, so please try to clarify your ideas before posting on Webmasters. Best way (I think) would be to clean this up here and then fag for moderator's attention requesting migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no idea what you're trying to accomplish, but I believe you're seriously misguided about how a PHP-based website works.

If you set up `.htaccess`-rules to stop the browser from accessing any PHP-file, it is not only ajax that will be affected.  *Every page* on your Drupal website will return 403 to any visitor, including `index.php` in the root directory.  I doubt that you want this.

If you've got Apache configured correctly for PHP, the *contents* of a PHP-file are never transmitted to the client - only the result of processing it server side.  Just point your browser to `sites/default/default.settings.php` to see how this works.  Unless you've really munged your Drupal configuration, you should not need to do *anything* to stop the PHP-files from being browsed.